# Umbraco: Use data from partial view in HTML meta title

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco, surface-controller

I've got a surface controller that calls an external api to get a list of stores in a given city and state.  The problem is I need to use some data that I get back from that call in the

```
<title></title>
```

Which exists in the head of my Master Template.  As far as I can tell there's no way to pass data up from a partial view into the Master Template.  I'm stumped.

I tried using ViewBag but it renders the head before my partial view sets the value and it just comes up null.

Template:

```
<head>
    <title>ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <div class="main foreground container">
            <h1>@CurrentPage.title</h1>
            @CurrentPage.mainColumn

            @Html.Action( "StoreDirectory", "Locations" )

    </div>
</body>
```

Partial View:

```
@model Fromm.Web.Consumer.Models.StoreDirectoryModel
@using Fromm.Model;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Model.Title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really umbraco related because you would have the same problem when you invoke an ChildAction from a template when you would be using plain MVC.

The only way to solve this is using a [MvcRenderController](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/custom-controllers) for your complete template, rather then a surfaceController.

Then... If the titletag is specified in the master document make it overridable in the templates using a section:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("metaTitleTag"))
{
    @RenderSection("metaTitleTag", required: true)
}
else
{
    <title>@Model.Name</title>
}
```